# VS 2005 Test Project Not Opening

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I'm trying to open a VS 2005 solution which includes a VS2005 Test project. When the solution is opened, all projects apart from the Test project are loaded. When I try to load the Test project, I get the following error:

**The project type is not supported by this installation**

My VS instance: Visual Studio 2005 Professional
                Version 8.0.50727.762 (SP .050727-7600)

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: can you open the project outside of the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS 2005 Professional did not support Test projects (VS 2008 Pro *does* support Test projects).  For VS 2005 with unit testing, you would have needed Test Edition or Team Suite.

Comment: Thanks Marcie. I think that would solve it. However, my colleague who created the project also has Professional. Or at least thats what the About page displays. Might there be some plug-in or add-on?

Comment: Nevermind. Turns out my colleague used another installation for it. It was Team System. I'm gonna try to find a TS installation.