# How to enable Unit test in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

In VS2008, when I right click a source file, there is a menu item "Create Unit test", but on another PC w/ VS2005, when I right click, there is no such menu item.  How to make the Unit Test in context menu in VS2005?  I guess probably some option is not enabled.  thanks

VS2005 pro does not have Unit test integrated. see [VS 2005 Test Project Not Opening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678782/vs-2005-test-project-not-opening).  I guess I need install some test framework like NUnit in VS2005

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678782/vs-2005-test-project-not-opening and it says VS2005 pro does not have test support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS2005 pro does not have Unit test integrated. see [VS 2005 Test Project Not Opening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678782/vs-2005-test-project-not-opening).  so need install some test framework like NUnit